# How To Arrive At Ground State Metric of Kaluza-Klein Theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, compactification, kaluza-klein

The ground state metric, after an extra dimension of space is compactified (to a circle) in Einsteinian gravity, is the metric which corresponds to the R_4 × S_1 geometry of the separated dimensions. How does one arrive at this metric, from the cross product of 4 dimensional gravity  and the extra dimension?

For reference:

1. [JM Overduin's cover of Kaluza-Klein Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9805018) , on page 21 mentions the ground state metric, as the "vacuum expectation value of the full metric", which "determines the topology of the compact space". It says that it is, topologically, R_4 × S_1.
2. In [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258884/ground-state-metric/258895#258895) to a question of mine, Luboš Motl explained that the ground state metric, in practice, is the one for which the geometry is the Cartesian product R_4 × S_1.

So, how could one derive the ground state metric, knowing the topologies R_4 and S_1, and taking their cross product?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is - the usual treatments of Kaluza-Klein rather explicitly do the dimensional reduction and end up with a 4D metric. Can you make more explicit what you're asking about (by giving references, examples, and formulae)?

Comment: Supposing you knew the topologies of R_4, and S_1, and took their cross product. How would you find the resultant metric?

Comment: @J.P.Escarcega Given Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$, $(N,h)$ there is no unique way to give $M\times N$ a metric. For instance, $g+h$ works, but so does $g+fh$ where $f$ is a function that is never zero.